# When moving one's head to answer a question does "nod" mean yes and "shake" mean no?

Tags: meaning

I was reading the Green Mile by Stephen King and when John Coffey shook his head in answer to questions it was implied that the word "nod" referred to the lowering and raising of his head in affirmation and the moving of his head side to side is negatory. Is this correct in usual speech? I thought to shake ones head was ambiguous and could mean "yes" or "no"?

Answer (score 10):

Head movements vary in their meaning depending on the culture in question. In general, in countries where English is the native language, a "nod" (not a "node") is an up and down movement of the head meaning "yes." A head shake is a side to side movement meaning "no." At least for most English speakers in Britain and America, a nod never means no, and a shake never means yes. This is somewhat oversimplified and variations exist, but for the most part, the basic pattern is as I have stated it.

Comment: I always thought that the shake means no because it is the movement of a child's head when the child does not want to be fed.

Comment: +1 And *nodding* is sometimes referred to as *bobbing* ones head, also meaning *yes*.

Comment: Your  “A head shake is a side to side movement meaning 'no'” sentence is ambiguous; the head waggle (side to side movement of the top of the head, with eyes facing forward) used in southern India for *yes* (or, at least, not *no*; sometimes it's *maybe*) also is a side to side movement.  The Englishy head shake that means *no* is a side to side head movement where the eyes move in a horizontal arc.

Comment: @jwpat7’s point is an important addition, since (perhaps especially in the US?), the head waggle does _not_ mean ‘no’ (unlike the head shake, which does), but can be used together with both ‘yes’ and ‘no’ answers. It does not indicate the answer itself, but rather that you are reflecting on what your answer will be.

Comment: @jwpat7 The details of these movements can be elusive in description, and the exact terms never do a great job of encompassing the totality of the movement. "Shake," however, is the standard term for the movement we use in the U.S. for the head movement we use to indicate "no," and so in that sense, my statement is not ambiguous at all. Note, however, that my answer includes numerous qualifications. I state that my answer is oversimplified, variations exist, and that my description works for _most_ people in Britain and the U.S. I don't think anyone could take it as gospel for every human.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Furthermore, I am familiar with the waggle to which jwpat refers. As it happens, my point in my comment above is supported by the fact the his description is not complete. The waggle is not merely a side to side movement of the top of the head. It also requires a simultaneous corresponding movement of the chin in the opposite direction, which makes it quite a unique movement, and one rather difficult to imitate by those who didn't grow up with it. Also, its use isn't restricted to southern India. It's a rather lovely gesture of assent. _But what one word describes it?_

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: Similarly, I would expect a nod to mimic the nod you give when you acknowledge someone, i.e. the (mostly male) way of saying hello nonverbally. Saying yes usually entails acknowledging something (as true); so the gesture retained its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with the response that indicated that a "nod" or movement of head up and down means "yes" in most English speaking cultures and a "shake"; side to side movement of head indicates "no."  However, there appears to be regional differences in the US.  While I grew up in the Northeast, I also lived in the South; and there I often heard the expression "shake your head 'yes' if you agree". But in those instances the person would be meaning what I would call "nod" the head; as in up and down. One in the South would also say, "Shake your head 'no'"; meaning move the head from side to side.  So, there appears to be a different interpretation of "shake your head" regionally.

Answer (score 0):

In British English nod means yes. One would write she nodded her head... without any mention of yes. Likewise a shake means no and the work no is not written